# Access variable inside the same array it was set in

Tags: php, arrays

I want to access a variable inside the same array it was set in to do String-Operations and stuff like that.

I have an array with information about the paths to certain directories. Now I want to do `str_replace()` to remove `$options['path_htdocs']` from `$options['path_absolute']` to get the path I want but PHP says it doesn't know that variable:
`** Notice: Undefined variable: options in path\to\files\index.php on line 12**`

```
// shortened version of that array
$options = [
  'path_absolute' => formatPath( dirname(__FILE__) ),
  'path_htdocs' => formatPath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ),
  'path_from_docroot' => ?
];
```

Is this possible, impossible or total nonsense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your array isn't defined, you can't reference it whilst defining it, which means you'll have to do it one of two ways:

```
$options = [
  'path_absolute' => formatPath( dirname(__FILE__) ),
  'path_htdocs' => formatPath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ),
  'path_from_docroot' => str_replace(formatPath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ), '', formatPath( dirname(__FILE__) ))
];
```

or

```
$options = [
  'path_absolute' => formatPath( dirname(__FILE__) ),
  'path_htdocs' => formatPath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ),
];

$options['path_from_docroot'] = str_replace($options['path_htdocs'], '', $options['path_absolute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can access array elements with scopes and permofm your replace assigning to `$options['path_from_docroot']` your new string

```
$options['path_from_docroot'] = str_replace($options['path_htdocs'], '', $options['path_absolute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `path_from_docroot` is the last index You need to process, You could proceed like this:

```
$options = [
  // ...
  'path_absolute' => formatPath( dirname(__FILE__) ),
  'path_htdocs' => formatPath( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ),
  // ...
];

$options['path_from_docroot'] = str_replace($options['path_htdocs'], '', $options['path_absolute']);
```